# Error loading a CPP file in RStudio with Microsoft R

Tags: r

I installed Microsoft R Open 3.5.1, tried to load a cpp  with `Rcpp::sourceCpp('TSDecompositionMissing.cpp')` and I'm getting this error:

`Error in system(cmd, intern = !showOutput) : 
  'C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/R' not found`

I added the `verbose` flag and then I'm seeing:

```
...
Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: C:/Users/julio/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpyqXrSJ/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-0.12.18/sourcecpp_88d456ea7b2a

C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/R Open/R-3.5.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o "sourceCpp_4.dll" "" "TSDecompositionMissing.cpp"  
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("TSDecompositionMissing.cpp", verbose = T) : 
  Error 127 occurred building shared library.
```

I checked my `Sys.getenv()` and I can see two relevant paths that do not exist (at least `PROGRA~1` doesn't):

`R_DOC_DIR                           C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/R Open/R-3.5.1/doc
R_HOME                              C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/R Open/R-3.5.1`

Has somebody encountered this error before?

EDIT:

So, I realised the PATH `C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/` exists and I think the problem is the folder after that which is named "R Open". It does not like the blank space

Comment: try reinstalling either MRO, RStudio or both

Answer (score 1):

After [Hong Ooi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474349/hong-ooi) suggestion, I uninstalled Rtools 3.4, installed Rtools 3.5, reinstall MRO 3.5, R 3.5 and RStudio and now everything is working. The problem was probably RTools 3.5 was missing.